# How to submit an abstract for a conference?

Tags: paper-submission, conference, abstract

I have recently composed an abstract for an upcoming conference. But, as this is my first time participating in an academic activity like this, I am not sure how to submit it.

Do I just write a cover letter and attach the abstract in the doc file?

Comment: Why not just email the organisers of the conference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each conference will have its own submission portal, likely some buggy piece of crap. Follow the instructions for the conference you are submitting to.

Likely, you will input your abstract into a text box (not submit a file), and you most likely will not have a cover letter. Conferences have to review a lot of abstracts and cover letters are just noise.